# Why cannot I run rebar3 commands in an application generated with rebar3?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erlang-supervisor, erl, rebar3

I have been trying to generate a rebar3 application, however I have encountered a problem, I have generated new app using rebar3, and when I try to compile it I get error as such:

```
> ===> Verifying dependencies...
> ===> Uncaught error in rebar_core.
```

The same error is given when I try to use rebar3 shell. However I can use command rebar3 shell in every other directory including sub directories of the generated application.

rebar3 version returns:

```
rebar 3.14.0-rc1+build.4613.reffb58aa1f on Erlang/OTP 22 Erts 10.6
```

I ahve no idea what might cause the error and will be thankfull for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas.

1. Try setting `DEBUG` and run your rebar3 command, i.e. `export DEBUG=1`.
2. You are running a release candidate for a new rebar3 version, maybe try the latest `3.13.X` version.

Answer (score 0):

Try do `rebar clean` and remove `_build` folder in your application, then try run `rebar compile`